# If a sequence $a_{n}$ diverges, will the sequence $c_{n} = \beta \cdot a_{n}$ also diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $ \beta \neq 0$ be a real constant and $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence. If
$a_{n}$  diverges, is it possible to conclude that  $c_{n} = \beta \cdot a_{n}$ will also diverge?

I know that if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n} = + \infty$, then $c_{n}$ will also diverge. 
Will that still be true if $a_{n}$ oscillates, for example?

Comment: If you don't know that the limit of the product of two convergent sequences is the product of the limits of each of them, then inspect the convergence of $(c_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ by definition.

Comment: If you have a sequence that oscillates, any non-zero constant factor does not prevent the oscillation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed. It's easier to look at the contraposition.

Assume that $\{\beta a_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ converges and let $L$ be its limit.

$\forall$ $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ $k \in \Bbb N$ such that: $\forall$ $n \ge k$, $|\beta a_n - L| < \epsilon$ ... $(*)$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$, by $(*)$: $\exists$ $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ / $\forall n \ge n_0$, $|\beta a_n - L| < \beta\epsilon$.

Dividing by $\beta$ both sides $(\beta \neq 0)$:

$|a_n - \frac{L}{\beta}| < \epsilon$.

Therefore: $\{a_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ converges to $\frac{L}{\beta}$.

Comment: (We can assume $\beta > 0$ without losing generality).

Comment: Using the contraposition was nice, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

By hypothesis we have:

$$\forall \ell\in\Bbb R\;\exists \epsilon_0>0,\quad \forall n\in\Bbb N,\; \exists n_0\ge n \;\text{such that}\; |a_{n_0}-\ell|\ge \epsilon_0$$
so for $c_n=\beta a_n$ it suffices to take $\frac{\epsilon_0}{|\beta|}$ to get the result.